# How can I undelete records from a SPList programmatically?

Tags: splistitem

There is a SharePoint List from which many records have been deleted using CAML. The records are available in the Recycle Bin.

Is there an way to recover the records using scripting/CAML etc ?
Since it's not efficient to recover the records manually.

Regards,
André

Comment: found something on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095884/how-to-restore-items-from-recycle-bin-sharepoint-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will restore all the items deleted from the specified list:

```
string listUrl = "web/relative/list/url"; // without leading slash!
var toRestore = new List<SPRecycleBinItem>();
foreach (SPRecycleBinItem recycleBinItem in web.RecycleBin)
{
    if (recycleBinItem.ItemType == SPRecycleBinItemType.ListItem
        && recycleBinItem.DirName.ToLowerInvariant() == listUrl.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        toRestore.Add(recycleBinItem);
    }
}

foreach (var itemToRestore in toRestore)
{
    itemToRestore.Restore();
}
```

Note: this code will require elevated privilegies, if you want to allow ordinary portal users to use it.